# JTable - cell editor is not high enough to fit the text

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I'm using standart JTable with standart cell editor to edit string values.
On some platforms, when cell editor is opened, text doesn't fit in it and part of the text is cut. For example "_" symbol is not visible, as well as it's hard to distingush "l" and "1" because the upper part of the symbol may be cut.

Probably I should just increase the cell height, but how much?

The result very depends on current Look & Fell, for example on Windows everything may be fine, but on Linux described effect appear.

Comment: What layout managers are you using?

Comment: @javapowered what is `standart cell editor`, did you mean that TableCell is editable, nothing else, or there is some JComponent inside TableCell

Comment: @Hovercraft - it's one of the few thingies a LayoutManager has nothing to do with :-)

Comment: @mKorbel standart cell editor is one used in `DefaultTableModel` where `getColumnClass` return `String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **calculate row height using table's font height**.

```
FontMetrics metrics = table.getFontMetrics(); 
int fontHeight = metrics.getHeight();
table.setRowHeight( fontHeight + delta );
```

*delta* can be anything you're comfortable with :)

Comment: getFontMetrics should accept argument, I wrote this way `FontMetrics metrics = table.getFontMetrics(table.getFont());`

Comment: hm is it possible to calculate how much "delta" do I need? I.e. how much extra space cell editor reserves for the border?

Comment: Border.getBorderInsets method can help you, I think

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Font use by your cell editor.

```
Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 22);
```